# Bubble Sort in Python Error message

Tags: python, typeerror, bubble-sort

I have been searching for hours and cant find an answer to why this program is not working...its copied out of coding for beginners....sorry for so basic but be great to know why.. ....I get error message:

```
line 5, in bubble_sort
    for element in range(len( array -1)- index):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

**this is the program:**

```
def bubble_sort( array):

    for index in range(len( array)):

        for element in range(len( array -1)- index):
            if array[ element]>array[element+1]:
                array[ element], array[ element+1] = \
                   array[ element+1] , array[element]

                print( '\tResolving element[', element,'] to' , array)

array = [5,3,1,2,6,4]
print( 'Bubble Sort...\nArray:', array)

bubble_sort(array)
print('Array:', array)
```

Comment: `len(array-1)` <- you try to subtract 1 from the array. Probably meant `len(array)-1`. Also: what is up with all the random whitespace after `(` or `[`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error message means is that you tried to subtract a number from a list.

Try

```
for element in range((len(array)-1) - index):
...
```

Comment: That's great . I checked online and it was a mistake in the book!! Not that i would have had any clue though..many thanks. The '(( '  was a great help as well.

Comment: don't forget to check as resolved so the question can be closed

Comment: What a day,,,where is the 'closed' button?